# How to correctly concatenate string in Powershell inline script in Azure DevOps?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I try to concatenate string to construct a path:

```
$SourceDirectoryPath = $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) + "/solution/project/bin/Debug"
$TargetFilePath = $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) + "/solution/project/bin/Debug/" + $(Release.ReleaseName) +$(Release.EnvironmentName)
```

but instead of getting string concatenated I get error for the second line:

> d:\a\r1\a : The term 'd:\a\r1\a' is not recognized as the name of a 
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable  program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At
>   D:\a_temp\9de874c9-3acd-4a19-a4dd-763074d38e40.ps1:2 char:25

where obviously `d:\a\r1\a` is a `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` but why it throws this error instead of just concatenating the string?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**tl;dr**

It is *Azure* that expands `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` *before* PowerShell sees the resulting commands; if the expanded `$(...)` value is to be seen as a *string* by PowerShell, it must be enclosed in *quotes* (`'$(...)'`):

- Using **`$(...)` (Azure macro syntax)**  **embeds the Azure variable's *verbatim value*** in the command text that PowerShell ends up interpreting.

  - **Note**: *Azure*'s macro syntax - which is evaluated *before* PowerShell sees the resulting command text - is not to be confused with *PowerShell*'s own [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), `$(...)`.
- **For *string* values this means that you situationally have to *surround the macro with quotes*** in order to make it work syntactically in PowerShell code, for which **`'...'`-quoting** (single-quoting) **is best**: `'$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'`

---

[Shayki Abramczyk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59860819/45375) provides an effective solution, but let me provide some **background information**:

The **variable expansion (substitution) that Azure performs via macro syntax (`$(...)`)** functions like a preprocessor: it **replaces the referenced variable with its *verbatim value***.

**You need to make sure that this verbatim value works *syntactically* in the context of the target command**.

As currently written:

> `$SourceDirectoryPath = $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) + "/solution/project/bin/Debug"`

turns into the following command *seen by PowerShell*, assuming that the value of Azure property `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` is `d:\a\r1\a`:

```
$SourceDirectoryPath = d:\a\r1\a + "/solution/project/bin/Debug"
```

This is a broken PowerShell command, because `d:\a\r1\a` - due to lack of quoting - is interpreted as a *command name or path*; that is, an attempt is made to *execute* putative executable `d:\a\r1\a` - see [`about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing).

Therefore, **in order for PowerShell to recognize the Azure-expanded value `d:\a\r1\a` as a *string*, you need to *quote* it** - see [`about_Quoting_Rules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules).

Since the expanded-by-Azure value needs no further interpolation, ***single* quotes are the best choice** (for both operands, actually):

```
$SourceDirectoryPath = '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)' + '/solution/project/bin/Debug'
```

In fact, **you don't need string concatenation (`+`) at all** in your case:

```
$SourceDirectoryPath = '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/solution/project/bin/Debug'
```

You could even combine that with expandable PowerShell strings (`"..."`), as long as the Azure-expanded value doesn't contain `$`-prefixed tokens that PowerShell could end up interpreting (unless that is your (unusual) intent).

One **caveat** re something like `"$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$projectRoot/bin/Debug"` (mixing an Azure-expanded value with a PowerShell variable reference) is that **Azure's  [macro syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax) (`$(...)`) looks the same as PowerShell's own [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)**, which is typically - but not exclusively - used in order to embed *expressions* in expandable strings (e.g., in pure PowerShell code, `"1 + 1 equals $(1 + 1)"`).

As of this writing, the [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) Azure help topic doesn't spell it out, but based on the [official comment in a GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/7023#issuecomment-579390672), **ambiguity is avoided as follows**:

- There is *no* escape mechanism; instead, `$(...)` constructs that do not refer to Azure variables are *left unchanged* and therefore *passed through* to PowerShell.
- In the typical case, PowerShell expressions will *not* look like an Azure variable reference (e.g, `$($foo.bar)` rather than `$(foo.bar)`), though hypothetically there can be ambiguity: `$(hostname)`, which is a valid PowerShell subexpression, could be preempted by Azure if a `hostname` Azure variable were defined.

  - In such a corner case, the solution is to avoid use of an *inline* script and instead place the code in an *external script file*.

Comment: Any advice for the situation where the variable can contain either a $ or a ' character? We used the single quote to get around the $-problem, but now we're facing a similar issue with the single quote character.

Comment: @Robba, I realize I never responded: For values with embedded `'` chars., you can use `"..."` quoting (assuming it doesn't also contain `"` chars.), though if the value _also_ contains `$`, this could lead to unwanted interpolation on the PowerShell side. If neither works for you, try accessing the variable as an - unquoted - _environment_ variable in PowerShell, which bypasses quoting problems (I cannot personally verify this, but supposedly all system and user Azure variables are also defined as _environment_ variables, in all-uppercase, with any `.` chars. in the name replaced with `_`)

Comment: thanks for the tip. I never thought of  accessing the value as an environment variable. In this case I just went with changing the password, though I do wonder if passwords/secrets are also passed in as environment variable, or if this is only done for regular variables.

Comment: @Robba, [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) say that secret variables aren't exported as environment variables _by default_ (for security reasons), but you can explicitly map them onto environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add quotes `" "` in the variables:

```
$SourceDirectoryPath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)" + "/solution/project/bin/Debug"
$TargetFilePath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)" + "/solution/project/bin/Debug/" + "$(Release.ReleaseName)" + "$(Release.EnvironmentName)"
```

Comment: That worked, but could you explain why this works?  I come from OOP languages and this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: In PowerShell, you must add quotes for strings, without it PowerShell thinks it's a command.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well.  $( ) outside of doublequotes would only be used to combine two or more statements.  Most people don't even know about it.

*This is actually incorrect.  I didn't know Azure Pipeline syntax.  It just shows how confusing combining both Powershell and Azure Pipeline can be.  This would work if $System were a Powershell object, not an Azure macro.*

```
$SourceDirectoryPath = $System.DefaultWorkingDirectory + '/solution/project/bin/Debug'
```