# Pipeline Array Variable (Classic) Causing powershell exception

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

In my pipeline I have a release variable named sourcefilenames with blank value
In PowerShell task1 I assign this variable with a string array using:

```
Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=sourcefilenames]$name")
```

Then on PowerShell task2 I reference that variable sucecssfully with:

```
Write-Host $(sourcefilenames)
```

And the values appear
But when I try to assign it to another variable so I can loop through the contents of the array:

```
$sourcenames= $(sourcefilenames)
```

It triggers an error:

"The term 'sourcefilename1' is not recognized as the name of...."

What could be wrong here? I have tried:

1. Declaring a new array in powershell task2
2. Passing $(sourcefilenames) directly in the foreach

all to no avail.

In a nutshell what I want to do is to loop through the array passed from task1 to task2

Comment: In short: Try `$sourcenames= "$(sourcefilenames)"`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59861171/45375) to the linked duplicate for an explanation.

Comment: Not sure if mine is related to concatenation. But I did try placing it in quotes and it gave me the same error.

Comment: It isn't about concatenation, it is about _Azure's_ `$(...)` macros getting expanded to values without any awareness of how they fit in to _PowerShell's_ syntax in the resulting command. The error message implies that the resulting line that PowerShell interpreted was verbatim `$sourcenames= sourcefilename1`, which predictably fails. Using `"..."` would result in  `$sourcenames= "sourcefilename1"`, which should _not_ result in the same error.