# Powershell script does not run when I have \ in my username

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have the below PowerShell script and it fails thinking that DS is a module. I am getting username from the Azure DevOps variables. The actual value of user name is **DS\TestUser**
Can someone help here

```
$serviceName = "Test"    
$username = $(UserName) 
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $(Password) -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $secpasswd
$binaryPath = "D:\Test\Test.exe"
New-Service -name $serviceName -binaryPathName $binaryPath -displayName $serviceName -startupType Automatic -credential $mycreds
```

[image]

I already tried converting the varible to ToString(), Out-String and Replacing \ with \

Comment: Change `$(UserName)` to `"$(UserName)"`

Comment: please don't post images of code/data/errors. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Using `$(...)` (Azure macro syntax) to embed an Azure variable's value in PowerShell code embeds its _verbatim value_ in the string that PowerShell ends up interpreting. For _string_ values this means that you situationally have to _surround the macro with quotes_ in order to make it work syntactically in PowerShell code, e.g. `'$(UserName)'` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59861171/45375) to the linked duplicate.

Comment: @mklement0 - that is the title of the post. [*grin*] i agree that a somewhat more direct title might work better.

Comment: I see, @Lee_Dailey - unfortunately, the post is locked, so the title can't be updated. I suggest not quoting the title verbatim - something like "Why? See [this Meta Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375)." should do. Or at least enclose the title in "..." to make it clear that you're _quoting_ something.

Comment: @mklement0 - i will use the quotes idea. i have a strong dislike for hiding URLs ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mathias R. Jessen mentioned in the comment, change `$(UserName)` to `"$(UserName)"` can solve this problem.